# Missing Rterm.exe

Tags: windows, rstudio

After installing R-4.3.2-win.exe on Windows 10, RStudio can't identify the newly-installed R 4.3.2.  This is because I'm missing Rterm.exe in C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin\x64.  It's present in my previous installation R 4.3.1 in the appropriate location.  Without using RStudio, Rgui.exe runs with no errors.

I uninstalled R and RStudio and re-installed.  Same problem.

How do I restore the lost Rterm.exe?

Install 4.3.2, expecting to have RStudio find the new installation by locating Rterm.exe.  Since that file is missing, RStudio can't find it.